# Using docker-compose with GELF log driver

Tags: logging, docker, docker-compose

According [to the official Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/logging/overview/), it is possible to get the `stdout` and `stderr` output of a container as [GELF messages](https://www.graylog.org/resources/gelf/) which is a format that is understood by e.g. [Graylog / Graylog2](https://www.graylog.org/) and [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).

This works fine when I run my containers manually from the command line. For instance,

```
docker run --log-driver=gelf --log-opt gelf-address=udp://localhost:12201 busybox echo This is my  message.
```

will send a log message to my Graylog2 server running on localhost which has a UDP input listener configured at port 12201.

Now, I want to use the same log options with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) which, according to the docs, [should be possible in principle](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#log-driver). However, the docs do not mention any log formats but `json-file`, `syslog` and `none` and when I include something like

```
my-container:
  container_name: ...
  build: ...
  ports: ...
  log_driver: "gelf"
  log_opt:
    gelf-address: "udp://localhost:12201"
```

in my `docker-compose.yml` file then `docker-compose up` fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.main", line 39, in main
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.docopt_command", line 21, in sys_dispatch
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.command", line 27, in dispatch
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.docopt_command", line 24, in dispatch
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.command", line 59, in perform_command
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.main", line 495, in up
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.project", line 265, in up
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.service", line 369, in execute_convergence_plan
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.service", line 270, in create_container
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.service", line 643, in _get_container_create_options
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.service", line 656, in _get_container_host_config
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/docker.utils.types", line 27, in __init__
ValueError: LogConfig.type must be one of (json-file, syslog, none)
```

For the record, this was on docker-compose 1.4.0 and docker 1.8.1, build d12ea79.

Apparently, Docker and docker-compose are not at the same level of implementation here. I just found that this has already been solved and included in the `Master branch` on Github, see
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1869
and
https://github.com/docker/docker-py/pull/724 .

Is there any way to either re-install docker-compose from the current Master branch or to add this to an existing installation manually? I could not find the file where the commit goes to anywhere on my host...

Comment: This is being fixed in `docker-py == 1.4.0` and will be fixed in the `docker-compose == 1.5.0` release

Comment: Yep, I saw that, too. However, `docker-compose == 1.5.0` will be released on [10/13/2015](https://github.com/docker/compose/wiki/1.5.0-Milestone-Project-Page), so I will probably have to wait a bit. I just tried to install the latest `master` from Github via `pip install -U https://github.com/docker/docker-py.git` and then `docker-compose --version` gives the correct output `1.5.0-dev`. Still, all docker-compose commands like `docker-compose up` fail with `raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.
Any idea on this?

Comment: It should be fixed on master now

Comment: Sorry, put the wrong link in the `pip` statement in my comment above, it should have been `pip install -U https://github.com/docker/compose/archive/master.zip`. However, I still get the same error. Does it work for you (or anyone else)?

Comment: I think I might have been mistaken, the code to fix this was just merged a few minutes ago. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am sorry to say that it still does not work for me, giving the same `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` as before. Anything else that I could be missing here? By the way, if I also update to the latest master of `docker-py`, the error becomes `from . import api
ImportError: cannot import name api
`. Thank you for your support though!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue has been fixed.

I have just tested logging to graylog2 using docker-compose [1.5.0rc2](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.5.0rc2)

You can try with this working example yaml:

```
example:
 container_name: example
 image: debian:wheezy
   command: /bin/sh -c "while true; do date && echo "hello"; sleep 1; done"
 ports:
  - "1234:1234"
 log_driver: "gelf"
 log_opt:
   gelf-address: "udp://graylog.example.com:12201"
   gelf-tag: "first-logs"
```

When container starts there is a warning

`example |  WARNING: no logs are available with the 'gelf' log driver`

But it does not seem to affect that messages are sent to graylog.

Comment: Nice. Now also works smoothly as described in the question.

Comment: That warning is included because the output you are viewing is generated from the same source as `docker logs` which is unavailable for off-box logging drivers.

Comment: This syntax won't work anymore for docker-compose v2 onwards, check the other answer for updated syntax

Comment: This is for docker-compose version 1 and now it is on version 3 now.
Version 2 and version 3 are using the same logging structure so it should be the answer from @nwinkler

Answer (score 26):

For Docker-Compose v2 services, the syntax has changed slightly, it's all under a new "logging" section now:

```
version: "2"

services:
  example:
    container_name: example
    image: debian:wheezy
    command: /bin/sh -c "while true; do date && echo "hello"; sleep 1; done"
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
    logging:
      driver: "gelf"
      options:
        gelf-address: "udp://graylog.example.com:12201"
        tag: "first-logs"
```

One important note: The address for `gelf-address` needs to be the external address of the server, as Docker resolves this address through the host's network.

Comment: what will be logs location when configured like above. And can we override that?